# menu within table cell not responding to z-index

Tags: html, css, html-table, z-index, sticky

I have a table similar to the one here: https://codepen.io/roberttaraya/pen/QVGRqg

[animated gif of table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G7hzB.gif)

html

```
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"
  integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">

  <table id="example">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Actions</th>
        <th>First name</th>
        <th>Last name</th>
        <th>Position</th>
        <th>Office</th>
        <th>Age</th>
        <th>Start date</th>
        <th>Salary</th>
        <th>Extn.</th>
        <th>E-mail</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <button class="actions1">show links</button>
          <ul class="actions-list actions1">
            <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </td>
        <td>Tiger</td>
        <td>Nixon</td>
        <td>System Architect</td>
        <td>Edinburgh</td>
        <td>61</td>
        <td>2011/04/25</td>
        <td>$320,800</td>
        <td>5421</td>
        <td>t.nixon@datatables.net</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <button class="actions2">show links</button>
          <ul class="actions-list actions2">
            <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </td>
        <td>Garrett</td>
        <td>Winters</td>
        <td>Accountant</td>
        <td>Tokyo</td>
        <td>63</td>
        <td>2011/07/25</td>
        <td>$170,750</td>
        <td>8422</td>
        <td>g.winters@datatables.net</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <button class="actions3">show links</button>
          <ul class="actions-list actions3">
            <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </td>
        <td>Ashton</td>
        <td>Cox</td>
        <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
        <td>San Francisco</td>
        <td>66</td>
        <td>2009/01/12</td>
        <td>$86,000</td>
        <td>1562</td>
        <td>a.cox@datatables.net</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <button class="actions4">show links</button>
          <ul class="actions-list actions4">
            <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </td>
        <td>Cedric</td>
        <td>Kelly</td>
        <td>Senior Javascript Developer</td>
        <td>Edinburgh</td>
        <td>22</td>
        <td>2012/03/29</td>
        <td>$433,060</td>
        <td>6224</td>
        <td>c.kelly@datatables.net</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <button class="actions5">show links</button>
          <ul class="actions-list actions5">
            <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </td>
        <td>Airi</td>
        <td>Satou</td>
        <td>Accountant</td>
        <td>Tokyo</td>
        <td>33</td>
        <td>2008/11/28</td>
        <td>$162,700</td>
        <td>5407</td>
        <td>a.satou@datatables.net</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <button class="actions6">show links</button>
          <ul class="actions-list actions6">
            <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </td>
        <td>Brielle</td>
        <td>Williamson</td>
        <td>Integration Specialist</td>
        <td>New York</td>
        <td>61</td>
        <td>2012/12/02</td>
        <td>$372,000</td>
        <td>4804</td>
        <td>b.williamson@datatables.net</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <button class="actions7">show links</button>
          <ul class="actions-list actions7">
            <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </td>
        <td>Herrod</td>
        <td>Chandler</td>
        <td>Sales Assistant</td>
        <td>San Francisco</td>
        <td>59</td>
        <td>2012/08/06</td>
        <td>$137,500</td>
        <td>9608</td>
        <td>h.chandler@datatables.net</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <button class="actions8">show links</button>
          <ul class="actions-list actions8">
            <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </td>
        <td>Rhona</td>
        <td>Davidson</td>
        <td>Integration Specialist</td>
        <td>Tokyo</td>
        <td>55</td>
        <td>2010/10/14</td>
        <td>$327,900</td>
        <td>6200</td>
        <td>r.davidson@datatables.net</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <button class="actions9">show links</button>
          <ul class="actions-list actions9">
            <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </td>
        <td>Colleen</td>
        <td>Hurst</td>
        <td>Javascript Developer</td>
        <td>San Francisco</td>
        <td>39</td>
        <td>2009/09/15</td>
        <td>$205,500</td>
        <td>2360</td>
        <td>c.hurst@datatables.net</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <button class="actions10">show links</button>
          <ul class="actions-list actions10">
            <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </td>
        <td>Sonya</td>
        <td>Frost</td>
        <td>Software Engineer</td>
        <td>Edinburgh</td>
        <td>23</td>
        <td>2008/12/13</td>
        <td>$103,600</td>
        <td>1667</td>
        <td>s.frost@datatables.net</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <button class="actions11">show links</button>
          <ul class="actions-list actions11">
            <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </td>
        <td>Jena</td>
        <td>Gaines</td>
        <td>Office Manager</td>
        <td>London</td>
        <td>30</td>
        <td>2008/12/19</td>
        <td>$90,560</td>
        <td>3814</td>
        <td>j.gaines@datatables.net</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <button class="actions12">show links</button>
          <ul class="actions-list actions12">
            <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </td>
        <td>Quinn</td>
        <td>Flynn</td>
        <td>Support Lead</td>
        <td>Edinburgh</td>
        <td>22</td>
        <td>2013/03/03</td>
        <td>$342,000</td>
        <td>9497</td>
        <td>q.flynn@datatables.net</td>
      </tr>
  </tbody>
  </table>

  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

css

```
.container {
  height: 300px;
  width: 600px;
  background-color: tan;
  overflow:auto;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

table tbody tr td, table thead tr th {
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 50px;
  width: 1px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

td:nth-child(1), th:nth-child(1) {
  position:sticky;
  position:-webkit-sticky;
  left: 0px;
  z-index:1;
  background-color:grey;
}

td:nth-child(2), th:nth-child(2) {
  position:sticky;
  position:-webkit-sticky;
  left: 74px;
  z-index:1;
  background-color:grey;
}

table thead tr th {
  background-color: red;
  position: sticky;
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  top: 0px;
  z-index: 5;
}

table thead tr th:nth-child(1), 
table thead tr th:nth-child(2) {
  z-index: 6;
}

ul {
  display: none;
}

li{
  position: relative;
}

.actions-list {
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 200px;
  width: 100px;
  top: 20px;
  left: 15px;
  z-index:10;
  background-color: pink;
}
```

js

```
$("button").click(function(e) {
  el = $("ul." + this.className).toggle()
})
```

The table has a sticky header and sticky left columns. Within one of the left columns I have a menu that toggles open with a link/button. When I toggle the menu open, I want it to be shown above and outside of the tables cells but as you can see from the codepen example, the menu is hidden behind the table cells, no matter what I set the z-index to.

Is there a way achieve the desired behavior?

Comment: what i ended up doing is following @rlejnieks and changing the menu's z-index with jquery  ` $("button").click(function(e) {
  el = $("ul." + this.className).toggle()
  
  $(".actions-list").parent().css("z-index", "auto")
  $(this).parent().css("z-index", "2")
}) `

Comment: you dont actually have to initially set the z-index like @rlejnieks did. i'm not sure why this works. my guess is that changing the element's z-index after it is rendered, gives it a different stacking context, allowing it to be rendered above everything else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not very pretty but works:

```js
$("button").click(function(e) {
  el = $("ul." + this.className).toggle();
  
  // add these lines
  $('button').parent().removeClass('above');
  $(this).parent().addClass('above');
})
```

```css
/* add this to css */
td.above {
    z-index: 10;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

remove the position from action-list class.

```
.actions-list {
  /*position: absolute;*/
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 200px;
  width: 100px;
  /*top: 20px;*/
  /*left: 15px;*/
  z-index:10;
  background-color: pink;
}
```

Hope this will help !

Comment: yeah... i dont want that expansion of the table column when i toggle the menu open. the desired effect i want is for the menu list to open above and outside of the table cell.